# C: are operations between members allowed in the struct declaration?

Tags: c, struct

I am trying to use a struct to represent an object with three properties, but the third property is dependent on the first two. So, I basically attempted this:

```
typedef struct{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z = x + y;
}xyz_type;
```

But I get a compiler error. Does the C language not support this sort of behavior or am I missing the correct syntax for something like this?
If it is not supported what would be a better way to achieve something like this?

Expected behavior: z will be initialized with the sum of the initialization values of the other two and then stay independent

Comment: Inline initialization of members in structures is not allowed at all in C. You might want to look up one of the factory patterns for how to create and initialize the structure.

Comment: Please describe what you expect this to do. Do expect that z will always be the sum of the other two? Forever, i.e. even if x or y get changed, automatically z will always be the sum? Or do you expect that z will be initialised with the sum of the initialisation values of the other two and then stay independant? Please describe.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I have added the information that was missing taken from the comments

Comment: My assumption about the required semantics was incorrect - I have modified my answer in light of the clarification - you may wish to review whether it is still acceptable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude : I appreciate that it may be a lot of work, but a full answer illustrating how the factory pattern might be used in this case might be interesting - for a full spectrum of solutions.  It might look like overkill for this, (and you might end up wishing it were C++), but the question may have been simplified for illustration purposes.

Comment: @Clifford: The answer is even better now, thanks for introducing me to the concept of macros!

Comment: How about a simple function like `xyz_type create_xyz(int x, int y) { return (xyz_type){ x, y, x + y }; }`

Comment: @ZKK : Please don't tell _anyone_ I introduced you to macros.  They are generally best avoided - I don't want to be responsible for the trouble you will get yourself in by enthusiastic but ill-considered macro use!  I have added Someprogrammerdude's suggestion to my answer.

Comment: it depends on the purpose, but in many cases you don't even need the third property and just calculate it from the other properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The struct defines a *type*, not an *instance*. You cannot define initialisation for a type.  For that you would need a *constructor* like that provided by C++, but not C.

However, you can refer to in instance of the structure within the structure's own initialiser:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
} xyz_type ;

xyz_type instance = 
         { 10,                         // x = 10
           5,                          // y = 5
           instance.x + instance.y } ; // z = 15


instance.x = 0 ; // x = 0, z is unchanged
```

You can be explicit about which members are being assigned in an initialiser:

```
xyz_type instance = { .x=10, 
                      .y=5,
                      .z=instance.x+instance.y} ;
```

which is useful in more complex structures with other members, however the ordering remains *critical* - members are assigned in the order they are defined in the `struct` definition, not the order they appear in the initialiser, so `z` in this case must be defined *after* both `x` and `y`.

This is not equivalent to a constructor, because it must be coded explicitly at each instantiation.  It is possible to automate the initialisation to some extent by writing a macro. For example:

```
#define XYZ_INIT( xinit, yinit ) {.x=(xinit),\
                                  .y=(yinit),\
                                  .z=(xinit)+(yinit)}
```

then;

```
xyz_type instance = XYZ_INIT( 10, 5 ) ;
```

Since macros can be problematic, and are not type-safe, you might prefer an initialiser function as below:

```
xyz_type create_xyz(int x, int y) 
{ 
    return (xyz_type){ .x = x, .y = y, .z = x + y }; 
}
```

then:

```
xyz_type instance = create_xyz( 10, 5 ) ;
```

Comment: @M.M : Thanks.  With regard to the syntax, since adopting C++ about 20 years ago, I am "unsafe" with respect to those parts of C that have never been adopted by C++.  Should have checked.  I in fact "guessed" the syntax from memory, then tested it at GDB Online, where either syntax is accepted without complaint - although the syntax I used was obsoleted since GCC 2.5!  Microsoft C compilation in VS2019 rejects it.  With respect to C99, I think that is a reasonable assumption today (even for Microsoft compilers), so instead I have simply removed the mention of C99 from the second example.

Comment: @M.M : Regarding initialisation using a non-const expression only working a block-scope that is an important point, but is no more a restriction that explicit assignment, which must also occur within a block.